# get match of string using regex that has curly braces and replace all incl curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to figure out how to construct a regex that can match any text inside curly braces, but also removes the curly braces on replacing.

Have the following strings/scenarios:

```
<span>Some text before {can be any text}<span>
<span>{can be any text} some text after<span>
<span>Some text before {can be any text} and some text after<span>
```

What I want, is replacing everything inside the curly braces including the braces itself and replace it with an HTML a tag.

**What I have tried:**

```js
let link = '<span>Some text {some text inside}</span>'
link = link.replace('\{([^}]+)\}', `<a href=${link} target="_blank" key="anchor">some text inside</a>`)
console.log(link)
```

if I console the link out, it still has the curly braces plus content inside, so not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Your regular expression isn't surrounded by `/.../`

Comment: but replace('/\{([^}]+)\}/') gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions should start and end with `/` instead of the normal string delimiters.

```js
let link = 'https://example.org'
let content = '<span>Some text {some text inside}</span>'
content = content.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/, `<a href="${link}" target="_blank" key="anchor">some text inside</a>`)
console.log(content)
```

Comment: ohh, damn I didn't see that mistake, now I get it why it did not work, thanks alot for pointing that out ;)